# Нет доступа к API новой почты

Tags: javascript, json, api

Ключ верный, в личном кабинете новой почты есть возможность протестить запрос, запрос сформирован верно. Когда пытаюсь стучать с хостинга к API новой почты вижу { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }

```
$(function() {
    var params = {
        "modelName": "Address",
        "calledMethod": "getCities",
        "methodProperties": {
            "FindByString": "Житомир"
        },
        "apiKey": "a7a279d6f4b1c3fa6e6667b058d58904"
    }

    $.ajax({
            url: "http://testapi.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/Address/getCities?" + $.param(params),

            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            },

            type: "POST",

            // Request body
            data: "{body}",
        })

        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })

        .fail(function() {
            console.log('FAIL');
        });

});
```

Помогите понять в чём дело

Comment: Уже понял, копировал пример кода с сайта новой почты и не заметил, что там написать testapi, слово test убрал, всё заработало

Comment: Что есть новая почта и чем она отличается от старой? Какой именно почтовый провайдер имеется в виду, мы должны догадаться в качестве упражнения?